# bundle install gives error Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from http://rubygems.org/

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, bundle, bundler

Running `bundle install` gave the following

> Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
>
> Retrying fetcher due to error (2/4): Net::HTTPServerException 403 "Forbidden"
>
> Retrying fetcher due to error (3/4): Net::HTTPServerException 403 "Forbidden"
>
> Retrying fetcher due to error (4/4): Net::HTTPServerException 403 "Forbidden"
>
> Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/

Followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194481/bundle-install-could-not-fetch-specs-from-https-rubygems-org) and changed to http in Gemfile. Problem Still exists. I didn't install any other ruby version. Default on Mac Ruby version : ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18], bundle version 2.0.1.

Running `bundle update` then gave

> Authentication is required for http://rubygems.org/. Please supply credentials for this source. You can do this by running: bundle config http://rubygems.org/ username:password

No idea what the credentials should be, but I signed up at rubygems.org and used that username/password (Pardon if that was silly) and got

> Bad username or password for http://username@rubygems.org/. Please double-check your credentials and correct them.

Followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53256307/4512432) and turned off IPV6 and still same problem.(If anything the errors showed up a little faster)

Infact now realised none of the gem command works and gives errors like

`gem install jekyll bundler`

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Net::HTTPServerException)
>    403 "Forbidden"

While I did install jekyll and bundler yesterday. Today I ran `bundle exec jekyll serve` and got

> Could not find gem 'minima (~> 2.0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
>   Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

Hence, it all started with trying to get Jekyll working.
OS : MacOS(10.14.3)

Comment: This issue looks like [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72527146/2334082) and I recommend the same workaround, adding `:ipv4_fallback_enabled: true` to `~/.gemrc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have a proxy in my organization's network which I knew would cause problems so I was infact using a different network. I finally tried to comment out the proxy settings in my .bash_profile, and it was still giving the same errors. I shut down the system and then tried again and it worked.

Such a bummer. Anyway I'm not deleting the question hoping for a better work around than this. I mean if every time I want to use gem I have to do this it's kind of a hassle.

Answer (score 1):

Using http instead of https in your Gemfile should do the trick.

Use:

http://rubygems.org

Answer (score 0):

**Disable IPv6 and HTTPS .**

(Windows) -

Open Gem file and replace :

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
```

with

```
source "http://rubygems.org"
```

then , Go To Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections
Right Click on your adapter , and select properties .

Untick IPv6 there